# Mongoose sort by populated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

well i have the following shemas:

```
    var BrandSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: {
          unique: true
        },
        lowercase: true
      },
      logo: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Image'
      }
    });

    var FollowActionSchema = new Schema({
      'actionDate': {
        type: Date,
        'default': Date.now
      },
      'brand': {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Brand'
      },
      'performer': {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      'type': String // followUser, folloBrand, followMerchant
    });
```

What i want is getting the user following brands, sorting by brand name, so for do that i did the query to FollowAction and find all the FollowActions that user did and then i populate the brand field.

So the problem is that i can't sort the query for the brand name, the only way i know to do that is by returning all documents and sort them from nodejs app. Anyone knows how can i do that?? or if i should change the shema structure??

The query that i do is:

```
       async.waterfall([
        function findActions(next) {
          var options = {
            query: {
              performer: userId,
              $or: [{
                type: 'followBrand'
              }, {
                type: 'followMerchant'
              }]

            },
            projection: {
              actionDate: 1,
              brand: 1,
              merchant: 1,
              type: 1
            },
            sort: '-actionDate',
            pagination: pagination
          };
          utils.limitQuery('FollowAction', options, next);
        },
        function inflate(actions, next) {
          total = actions.count;
          var options = {
            projection: {
              name: 1,
              _id: 1,
              username: 1
            }
          };
          async.eachSeries(actions.result, function(action, done) {
            async.waterfall([
              function inflateAction(done) {
                action.inflate(options, done);
              },
              function addToArray(item, done) {
                trusted.push({
                  _id: item._id,
                  name: utils.capitalize(item.name || item.username),
                  type: item.name ? 'brand' : 'merchant'
                });
                return done(null, item);
              }
            ], done);
          }, next);
        }
      ], function(err) {
        callback(err, trusted, total);
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting before populating?

Comment: Please can you post your actual code where you do queries? So we can integrate with ours.

Comment: i edited the original post with the query. it's possible to sorting with populated field before populate this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mongoose API does seem to support sorting on populated fields, but there's a bug that breaks it entirely: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202. You get a result, but it's just plain wrong.

For small amounts of data, it's fine to sort the result array using Javascript [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Keep in mind that this directly modifies the sorted array though.

What I've done in this case is add a sort key property to the schema for the model you want to sort. For your example, you could do:

```
var FollowActionSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  'brandSortKey': { type: String },
  'brand': {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Brand'
  },
  // ...
});
```

This isn't perfect, because you'll have to explicitly set this property with the correct key yourself:

```
var FollowAction = Model('FollowAction', FollowActionSchema);

var aBrand = // some brand object

var f = new FollowAction({
   brand: aBrand._id,
   brandSortKey: aBrand.name
   // other properties
});
```

But, then you can sort directly via the Mongoose API (or MongoDB):

```
FollowAction.find({})
   .sort({ brandSortKey:1 })
   .exec(function (err, sortedResults) {
       // do something with sorted results.
   });
```

Comment: Oh, now I see that the question was asked 11 months ago. Sigh. SO n00b answer FAIL. :)

Answer (score -1):

Get the idea from this simple example

```
 Post.find({'_id': userId})
           .limit(10)
           .skip(0)
           .sort({'created_at':-1}) // this is used to sort
           .exec(function(error, result){
            if(!error){
              // console.log(result);
              res.send({data:result});
            } else{
              console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP question at all XD